# vsftpd Login is not successful

Tags: vsftpd

I tried installing vsftpd in Ubuntu 15 through `apt-get install vsftpd` and configured the /etc/vsftpd.conf file. But when I type in terminal as `ftp localhost`, it prompted for username and password. I entered `ftp` as username but no idea about the password. Then it gives an error like `530 Non-anonymous sessions must use encryption.`.

How can I configure thesecredentials> Where these credentials are mentioned ?

Here is my `vsftpd.conf` file

```
# Run standalone?  vsftpd can run either from an inetd or as a      standalone
# daemon started from an initscript.
listen=NO
#
# This directive enables listening on IPv6 sockets. By default, listening
# on the IPv6 "any" address (::) will accept connections from both IPv6
# and IPv4 clients. It is not necessary to listen on *both* IPv4 and IPv6
# sockets. If you want that (perhaps because you want to listen on specific
# addresses) then you must run two copies of vsftpd with two configuration
# files.
listen_ipv6=YES
#
# Allow anonymous FTP? (Disabled by default).
anonymous_enable=NO
#
# Uncomment this to allow local users to log in.
local_enable=YES
#
# Uncomment this to enable any form of FTP write command.
write_enable=YES
#
# Default umask for local users is 077. You may wish to change this to   022,
# if your users expect that (022 is used by most other ftpd's)
local_umask=022
#
# Uncomment this to allow the anonymous FTP user to upload files. This only
# has an effect if the above global write enable is activated. Also, you will

# obviously need to create a directory writable by the FTP user.
#anon_upload_enable=YES
#
# Uncomment this if you want the anonymous FTP user to be able to create
# new directories.
#anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
#
# Activate directory messages - messages given to remote users when they
# go into a certain directory.
dirmessage_enable=YES
#
# If enabled, vsftpd will display directory listings with the time
# in  your  local  time  zone.  The default is to display GMT. The
# times returned by the MDTM FTP command are also affected by this
# option.
use_localtime=YES
#
# Activate logging of uploads/downloads.
xferlog_enable=YES
#
# Make sure PORT transfer connections originate from port 20 (ftp-data).
connect_from_port_20=YES
#
# If you want, you can arrange for uploaded anonymous files to be owned by
# a different user. Note! Using "root" for uploaded files is not
# recommended!
#chown_uploads=YES
#chown_username=whoever
#
# You may override where the log file goes if you like. The default is shown
# below.
#xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
#
# If you want, you can have your log file in standard ftpd xferlog format.
# Note that the default log file location is /var/log/xferlog in this case.
#xferlog_std_format=YES
#
# You may change the default value for timing out an idle session.
#idle_session_timeout=600
#
# You may change the default value for timing out a data connection.
#data_connection_timeout=120
#
# It is recommended that you define on your system a unique user which the
# ftp server can use as a totally isolated and unprivileged user.
#nopriv_user=ftpsecure
#
# Enable this and the server will recognise asynchronous ABOR requests. Not
# recommended for security (the code is non-trivial). Not enabling it,
# however, may confuse older FTP clients.
#async_abor_enable=YES
#
# By default the server will pretend to allow ASCII mode but in fact ignore
# the request. Turn on the below options to have the server actually do ASCII
# mangling on files when in ASCII mode.
# Beware that on some FTP servers, ASCII support allows a denial of service
# attack (DoS) via the command "SIZE /big/file" in ASCII mode. vsftpd
# predicted this attack and has always been safe, reporting the size of the
# raw file.
# ASCII mangling is a horrible feature of the protocol.
#ascii_upload_enable=YES
#ascii_download_enable=YES
#
# You may fully customise the login banner string:
#ftpd_banner=Welcome to blah FTP service.
#
# You may specify a file of disallowed anonymous e-mail addresses. Apparently
# useful for combatting certain DoS attacks.
#deny_email_enable=YES
# (default follows)
#banned_email_file=/etc/vsftpd.banned_emails
#
# You may restrict local users to their home directories.  See the FAQ for
# the possible risks in this before using chroot_local_user or
# chroot_list_enable below.
chroot_local_user=YES
#
# You may specify an explicit list of local users to chroot() to their home
# directory. If chroot_local_user is YES, then this list becomes a list of
# users to NOT chroot().
# (Warning! chroot'ing can be very dangerous. If using chroot, make sure that
# the user does not have write access to the top level directory within the
# chroot)
#chroot_local_user=YES
chroot_list_enable=NO
# (default follows)
#chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
#
# You may activate the "-R" option to the builtin ls. This is disabled by
# default to avoid remote users being able to cause excessive I/O on large
# sites. However, some broken FTP clients such as "ncftp" and "mirror" assume
# the presence of the "-R" option, so there is a strong case for enabling it.
#ls_recurse_enable=YES
#
# Customization
#
# Some of vsftpd's settings don't fit the filesystem layout by
# default.
#
# This option should be the name of a directory which is empty.  Also, the
# directory should not be writable by the ftp user. This directory is used
# as a secure chroot() jail at times vsftpd does not require filesystem
# access.
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
#
# This string is the name of the PAM service vsftpd will use.
pam_service_name=vsftpd
#
# This option specifies the location of the RSA certificate to use for SSL
# encrypted connections.
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
ssl_enable=YES
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
allow_anon_ssl=NO
force_local_data_ssl=YES
force_local_logins_ssl=YES
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=YES
ssl_sslv3=YES
```

Answer (score 27):

To solve `530 Non-anonymous sessions must use encryption..`

I used these settings in vsftp.conf file.

```
force_local_logins_ssl=NO
force_local_data_ssl=NO
```

Comment: Doesn't this just disable encryption for local users? Isn't there a way to connect as a local user with encryption?

Comment: ftp command in linux is a plaintext utility. It cant connect with encryption. In order to use encryption you can add/check certificate directives and use sftp utility to connect with encryption.

Comment: It either needs this solution and then connecting through `ftp://` , or force ssl and then connecting through `ftps://` only.

Answer (score 2):

this is my configuration (on aws):

/etc/vsftpd.conf

```
listen=YES
listen_port=12345
pasv_address=<mypublicIP>
pasv_addr_resolve=YES
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_min_port=13000
pasv_max_port=13100
port_enable=YES
local_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
ascii_upload_enable=YES
ascii_download_enable=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
chroot_list_enable=YES
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
ls_recurse_enable=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=ftp
```

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root /etc/vsftpd.chroot_list <-- here you need to add the user created(one for line)

for the user creation:

```
useradd -m -d /HOME/OF/USER USERNAME
```

and for set the password (or change)

```
password USERNAME
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. But I didn't get what `listen_port=12345` is. Can you elaborate it a bit ? Another doubt also, do I need to create the vsftpd.chroot_list file by myself? Because there is no such file inside etc directory.

Comment: listen_port is the port it will listen on for incoming FTP connections(you can use the 21 port, the ftp default port) and yes you need to create vsftpd.chroot_list

Answer (score 0):

Change your configuration in /etc/vsftpd.conf by editing the line

```
allow_anon_ssl=NO
```

to

```
allow_anon_ssl=YES
```